# php html input filed limit

Tags: php, arrays, input

i've just noticed that if i have a lots of input fields with unique names on my form, sometimes the data does not get passed to the php page that is processing it. however, if instead of naming each field like this:

```
<input type="text" name="userid-1121" value="1">
<input type="text" name="userid-1122" value="1">
```

if i build the names into an array like this:

```
<input type="text" name="userid[1121]" value="1">
<input type="text" name="userid[1122]" value="1">
```

the array method doesnt seem to loose any posted data.

Just wondering if this is normal and if my solution of using the array method is better?

thanks

Comment: The array way is the way to go, you will keep a lot easier tracking.

Comment: if you want to post all the data with input elements name as same then you need to keep the name as array.

Comment: Well, you don't have to, but it is suggested.

Comment: Do you use "GET"? There is a limit on the GET length.

Comment: Can you explain how @DainisAbols

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a lot of input with different names, every input is part of the superglobal variables `$_GET` or `$_POST` and it's affected by the directive: [max_input_vars](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars), so your solution of using an array is valid because you are limiting the number of different variables. Other solution is to increase the value of this directive in your `php.ini`

Answer (score 0):

There is no **better** way, just easier.

If you use the array method, it will be more easier to read / pass the data later on.

Apart from that, they are both the same.